# Is NEC 2020 requirement for 240V GFCI grandfathered for add-on outlets?

Tags: electrical, gfci

There's been some discussion on this board about the NEC 2020 requirement for GFCI on 240V ("250V") outlets. I assume houses built prior to that new rule won't need to be retrofitted. Is GFCI required when adding a new 240V outlet in the garage? Years down the road, what are the chances an inspector will flag it to potential buyers?

https://www.dli.mn.gov/sites/default/files/pdf/NECFAQ20.pdf

Comment: Think that for putting a new circuit today, it has to be GFCI protected.  A circuit already in, does not(usually the case).  Just changing the receptacle would not mean it needs to be brought up code, upgrading the cable and receptacle and it does need to be to code and protected.

Comment: Circuits can be grandfather, houses can't.  100 year old houses can keep the circuits already in it.  Any new circuits made must be done to new code, but can keep the old circuits as they are, but a good idea to bring them up to code, if done to very old code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not grandfathered. GFCI required *for receptacles*. 100% chance of being caught. The date for NEC compliance purposes is the date on the permit.  Unpermitted work has no permit, so its date is the future.

Hard-wired 240V loads don't need GFCI protection.

If this is for electric vehicle charging, you are falling into a very common novice mistake. EVSEs should not be on GFCI, because they have a much superior GFCI of their own.

The little "fits in a shoebox" EVSE that comes with the car is intended to live in the trunk and be used for *opportunity charging* on the road.  It should not be your primary EVSE.

Comment: Actually, it gets more complicated. If I read the linked document correctly (which is not necessarily the case...) for garage/basement/kitchen/bathroom/etc. most hard-wired circuits are exempt from GFCI requirements (and therefore, install a hard-wired EVSE and end of story) but it seems that most outdoor circuits (HVAC, etc.) now require GFCI even for hard-wired loads, though the document also makes it clear that it is only for new stuff, not direct replacement of existing equipment.

Comment: "EVSEs should not be on GFCI" ... Are outlets intended for EVSE use exempted from the GFCI rule? J1772 EVSE adapters are readily available online with a myriad of plugs: 6-50, 14-50, 14-30, etc

Comment: The ideal situation (but whether allowed or not will depend on the particular equipment) is to **hard wire** EVSEs. That (a) removes a point of failure (loose plug) and (b) eliminates the GFCI requirement under current NEC rules. I really don't understand why, except when required by code (sometimes jurisdiction specific) anyone would install any major permanently installed appliance (dishwasher, disposal, oven, EVSE, etc.) cord/plug/receptacle instead of hard-wired. Just makes no sense to me. (Washer, dryer, refrigerator are different - but they're not attached to a wall or cabinet or sink.)

Comment: @pmont If your question is about EVSEs particularly, I can expand on that.  What you're missing is that **hard-wiring the EVSE** is a choice on the menu.  When you hard-wire the EVSE, there is no need for *a second, stupider* GFCI.

Comment: In fact, I just checked the current Tesla Wall Connector https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/support/charging/Gen3_WallConnector_Installation_Manual.pdf and it doesn't even discuss plug/cord connection - it only talks about different ways to route the wires (hot/hot/ground - no neutral needed) into the box. Not even "on the menu" - Tesla *assumes* that you are hard-wiring.

Comment: The only times anything bigger than a 5-20 cord/plug (i.e., convenience charging "wherever") makes sense for an EVSE are (a) plugging in at an RV park that doesn't have EVSEs or (b) in a rental (because the landlord won't pay for a new circuit and EVSE but you can plug into the dryer 14-30).

Comment: @manassehkatz Yes, the *portable/shoebox* travel EVSE uses a NEMA 14-50 is so you can charge at RV parks. *That does not reflect how wall-mount EVSEs should be wired*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine True. But even if you have to lower the rate (32A or 40A) due to service or panel limitations, hard-wiring still makes more sense than plug/receptacle.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica makes sense, BUT if hardwired is a must have (not to need GFCI) it only applies for breaker to the outlet. What if you then plug in the appliances (or EVSE charger) with a cable?

Comment: @Ruskes I am confused, since hardwiring an EVSE means no socket is used at all.  If it's plug-in and the state requires GFCI for sockets, then GFCI it is.